# Creating a function that searches for a string within a string and runs certain parameters using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that will negate a given string when function is used by adding 'not' to the start of the string that I inputed. For example, I input 'Happy' through the function and the output will be 'not happy'. If word 'not' is present in the user input string it will just print the string given.I have sample code that is not working properly and suggestions?

Here is code:

```
function negate(word) {
  var negative_string= 'not '+ word;
  return negative_string

  if (word.indexOf("not")>0);
  return word
}

negate('happy')
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're returning `'not ' + word;` without doing any sort of check to see if 'not' is a part of the original word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do your job.

```
function negate(word)
{
  if(word.indexOf("not") > -1)
    return word;
  return 'not '+word;
}
```